# How to setup limited remote access for employee?

Tags: remote-access

I would like to hire someone for web scrapping. She or he should be able to log on my PC and then download the things directly to one of my folders. However, I only want to grant them access to a web browser and that folder.

Is there any way of doing this?

I was thinking of installing a virtual machine (using virtualbox) and have them log in to that machine via teamviewer and then they download everything into a shared folder between the host (my PC) and the virtual machine.

However I am not sure if this will work and if there are better solutions... Ideally I would like to continue working on my PC, while there are doing the download in the background.

Comment: What OS? They shouldn't need a browser to web-scrap.

Comment: @MarkScheck I would use Windows as a host, and Ubuntu in virtualbox

Comment: Why would they need a browser to webscrape? Really you need just python, or the standard utilities curl, sed, grep.  So I think you have a VM is probably the way to go then.